# Why use exec.isTerminated() before exec.shutdown() with ExecutorService in java?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, executor

I was studying threads and came across the following code and have some concerns

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

exec.execute(left);
exec.executed(right);

if (!exec.isTerminated()) {
    exec.shutdown();
    exec.awaitTermination(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

int result = left.getResult() + right.getResult();
```

If all tasks are terminated then if condition will be False and thread pool won't be terminated as there's no shutdown command outside the if condition.

So is the following correct:

1. So shouldn't there be a shutdown outside if as well?
2. Why even have the if condition the shutdown() waits for all the pre-submitted task to be completed and we can even get rid of awaitTermination()?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to call `isTerminated()`.  From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#isTerminated%28%29):

> Note that `isTerminated` is never `true` unless either `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` was called first.

So it follows that `exec.isTerminated()` is always false in that code.  The `if` statement is pointless, since its body will always execute.

The `shutdown()` method [does not wait for anything:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29)

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

Therefore, the `awaitTermination` call is still useful.  (But assuming five seconds is enough is not safe;  there are better ways to make sure all submitted tasks have finished.)